# Getting memcheck error in RPC code

Tags: c, rpc

When I run it with valgrind, I get the following output in the client terminal:

```
==7374== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7374== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7374== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7374== Command: ./rvotefor localhost bush 1
==7374== 
==7374== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7374==    at 0x4C2AD40: strcpy (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7374==    by 0x400A1C: vote_prog_1 (rvotefor.c:17)
==7374==    by 0x400BF8: main (rvotefor.c:84)
==7374== 
==7374== Invalid write of size 1
==7374==    at 0x4C2AD40: strcpy (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7374==    by 0x400A1C: vote_prog_1 (rvotefor.c:17)
==7374==    by 0x400BF8: main (rvotefor.c:84)
==7374==  Address 0x2 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7374== 
==7374== 
==7374== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7374==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2
==7374==    at 0x4C2AD40: strcpy (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7374==    by 0x400A1C: vote_prog_1 (rvotefor.c:17)
==7374==    by 0x400BF8: main (rvotefor.c:84)
==7374==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7374==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7374==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7374==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7374==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7374== 
==7374== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7374==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7374==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==7374== 
==7374== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7374== 
==7374== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7374== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7374== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault
```

And this in the server terminal:

```
==6841== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6841== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6841== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6841== Command: ./vote_server
==6841==
```

Could anyone help me get rid of this error? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side in `main()`, you make sure that `dummy` contains a string with at least 3 chars and a null terminator  (as there is at least 1 char in each argv[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235454.aspx) and argv[3]).

WHen you then call `vote_prog_1()` some of the first statements are:

```
char * votefor_1_arg;         // <=====  !! uninitialized pointer 
strcpy(votefor_1_arg,dummy);  // <=====  !! copy the more than 4 bytes in dummy
```

So you overwrite somewhere memory (uninitialized pointer) with at least 4 bytes contained in `dummy[]`, corrupting memory.

You have to allocate memory before using your pointer.  For example with `strdup()` ([linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) or [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235454.aspx)):

```
 votefor_1_art = strdup(dummy);   // <== allocates memory and copy the string
```

There is also a potential issue with `votefor_1(&votefor_1_arg, clnt);` as you pass to this function not the address of the argument, but the address of the poitner to the argument.  This coudl be correct, but can be wrong depending on the function's signature.  If you're confused about it, post the code of this function as well, so that we can check.

Comment: So, do I just add the line votefor_1_arg = strdup(dummy); after the line char * votefor_1_arg; ?

Comment: @MarthaPears Yes.  In fact that statement shall replace your strcpy().